# Cannot convert live() function to on() jQuery 1.7.2

Tags: jquery, paste

I have a function that uses the deprecated live() function, but no matter what I try, I cannot seem to get on() to duplicate the functionality.

Here's the working live() code:
  `$("#video_url").live("paste", function(){`

Here's the on() code that *should* be working:
  `$(".post-modal").on("paste", "#video_url", function(){`

`.post-modal` is the immediate parent of `#video_url`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Does `.post-modal` exist in the DOM at the time the code runs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try

```
$(document).on("paste", "#video_url", function(){
```

make sure the element to which you are delegating the event exists in the DOM like in your code element with class `.post-modal` should be at a higher level then the element with the id `video-url` and also present in the DOM at the time when the events are attached to the elements

Comment: Boom! That worked! Thanks so much. Does `document` work over `.post-modal` because `.post-modal` is dynamically loaded into the DOM?

Comment: The on() method needs to be bound to something that exists in the DOM at the time of the page load.

Comment: @jmohsenin There are a number of reasons why `document` may have worked over your other element.  The element must be present at the time the code executes.  `document` is always present.  It is possible your element is dynamically loaded after this code executes or even that you do not have the code in `document.ready`.  It is better to use a static ancestor element over `document` if possible for performance reasons.

Comment: yes you cannot delegate the events to dynamic elements hope you understand what i mean, you have to delegate the events to already present elements like `document` or `body` or some element that is parent of the dynamic element and is present at the time of DOM creation

Comment: @JayBlanchard @James Montagne @John X OK, but if I load the entire `.post-modal` dynamically and it is appended to the bottom of my DOM, I have no other choice then to use `document`, no?

Comment: that depends how your markup is being structured but using `document` is the safest bet